# Decoding h264 in mp4 fragment from IIS Smooth Streaming

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding, smooth-streaming

So I've decided to try and make my own client for IIS's Smooth Streaming as a learning exercise and I'm struggling to decode the mp4 fragments.

I have the following fragment:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/n32660d920g291c/part+1.mp4

Which when I try to decode using ffmpeg:

```
C:\>ffplay.exe -f h264 -vcodec h264 -g 52 "part 1.mp4"
ffplay version N-58502-g738ebb4 Copyright (c) 2003-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Nov 27 2013 22:09:34 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis--enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 55.100 / 52. 55.100
  libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavformat    55. 21.102 / 55. 21.102
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] non-existing PPS referenced    0B f=0/0
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] non-existing PPS 25 referenced
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] Invalid mix of idr and non-idr slices
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] sps_id out of range
    Last message repeated 4 times
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] sps_id out of range
    Last message repeated 4 times
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] slice type too large (24) at 0 0
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000001e58260] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000001e4fa00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 0000000001e4fa00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
part 1.mp4: could not find codec parameters
```

After reading I found the PPS/SPS comes from the CodecPrivateData in the manifest that IIS gives me, which I have as:

```
000000016764001eacd940a03da10005161501312d000f162d960000000168ebe3cb22c0
```

Binary: http://www.mediafire.com/download/hm3av6h3i1g7ojf/CodecPrivateData

Which I think is annex b 00000001[SPS]00000001[PPS] but I have no idea what to do with it, I've tried putting it at the beginning of the file but get the same error, I also tried taking just the data in the mdat and sending that to ffmpeg but I get

```
[h264 @ 0000000001da8a80] sps_id out of range 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
[h264 @ 0000000001da8a80] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 0000000001da8a80] sps_id out of range
[h264 @ 0000000001da8a80] slice type too large (24) at 0 0
[h264 @ 0000000001da8a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000001da8a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000001d9fa00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 0000000001d9fa00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
part 1 - Copy.mp4: could not find codec parameters
```

So I then tried putting the CodecPrivateData just before the mdat section and I then get this

```
[h264 @ 0000000001d38a80] sps_id out of range 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000000001d38a80] slice type too large (24) at 0 0
[h264 @ 0000000001d38a80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000000001d38a80] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000000001d2fa00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 0000000001d2fa00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (High)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
part 1 - Copy.mp4: could not find codec parameters
```

I seem to be missing something to get this to decode and I'm just not sure what so I'm hoping someone knowledgeable with h264 can help me out! Ultimately I want to get this working in DirectShow but even getting it to work in ffmpeg would be a massive help!

Answer (score 1):

mp4 fragments are not decodable on their own. If you wish to convert it to an mp4, you need to recreate the moov atom in its entirety. This includes making a avc1 atom that contains the extradata (sps/pps) in avcc format.